# What does IO generally mean?

Tags: io

What does it mean by

> an app using a lot of **IO**

what is **IO** in the first place?

Comment: just point with your mouse on the IO tag under your question and read the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally IO refers to Input Output.

Answer (score -1):

In programming, most of the time IO stands for **I**nput and **O**utput